# Im looking for a way to delete the bot command after the bot has posted in Discord code written in Discord.net

Tags: c#, discord, embed, discord.net

Below is The code after the embed message is posted I would like the bot to delete the command that it was give to post the embed. Also if anyone knows how to add a footer to this embed that would be awesome

````
if (raid == "gos")
{
   if (day == "Sun")
   {
       var filename = "gos_Sun.png";

       var embed = new EmbedBuilder()
       {
           Title = "Garden of Salvation",
           Description = "```" + day + ", " + date + " @ " + time + " " + ampm + " " + "\n" + description + "```" + description2,
           ImageUrl = $"attachment://{filename}",
       }.Build();

       SentEmbed = await Context.Channel.SendFileAsync(filename, embed: embed);

       await SentEmbed.AddReactionsAsync(myReactions);
   }
}
````

Comment: Just call DeleteAsync on the Context.Message. Also the embed builder has a footer property

Comment: Yea but when i do Footer = "React Below", I get an error

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type string to Discord.EmbedFooterBuilder so it dose not work like Description or Title dose and through all my research I can not get an example of using the Footer property

Comment: Well it's not a string when used like that. It's a footer builder or something like that. So you have to create and pass one of those

Answer (score 0):

````
   var footer = new EmbedFooterBuilder().WithText("React Below");


        if (raid == "gos")
        {
            if (day == "Sun")
            {
                var filename = "gos_Sun.png";


                var embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                {
                    Title = "Garden of Salvation",
                    Description = "```" + day + ", " + date + " @ " + time + " " + ampm + " " + "\n" + description + "```" + description2,
                    ImageUrl = $"attachment://{filename}",

                }.WithFooter(footer).Build();
````